# php: simplest way to turn an indexed two-dimensional array into an associatively indexed-by-a-contained-value two-dimensional array?

Tags: php, indexing, multidimensional-array

I continually find myself running queries on databases and getting multidimensional arrays representing rows back.  Unfortunately, the first level index is numeric, which isn't very informative.  I frequently have tables with identity strings in the table, and want to turn the resulting multidimensional array into something that's associatively indexed by that identity column.

An inelegant self-created custom function to do what I want:

```
function identity_associate($data, $identity_column='identity'){
    $res = array();
    foreach($data as $single_row){
        $loop_identity = $single_row[$identity_column];
        $res[$loop_identity] = $single_row;
    }
    return $res;
}
```

Obviously I could use a foreach loop each time I wanted to do this, or use that function to do it for me when I pass the data to it each time, but if there's a built-in way to do this trivially with native php functions, I'd prefer to use that to make the correction instead.  I tried to find something appropriate in the php docs for sorting and arrays, but couldn't find anything exact, and google wasn't much help either.  Anyone know of something php native or otherwise simpler?

i.e. I want to convert the data that I get when I query the database...

```
array(
  array(
    'user_id'=>45,
    'identity'=>'bob',
    'name'=>'Bob'
  ),
  array(
    'user_id'=>51, 
    'identity'=>'tchalvak', 
    'name'=>'TchalVak'
  )
);
```

into something more usable

```
array(
  'bob'=>array(
    'user_id'=>45, 
    'identity'=>'bob', 
    'name'=>'Bob'
  ), 
  'tchalvak'=>array(
    'user_id'=>51, 
    'identity'=>'tchalvak', 
    'name'=>'TchalVak'
  )
);
```

as optimized-ly as possible, since it's something that I would use everywhere all the time.

**Edit:**

I want to point out that I'm getting the data in that format from the database by calling a built-in function in PDO and it's returning the equivalent of the first array:

```
$statement->execute();
return $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

E.g. calling the sql below:

```
$data = query('select name, user_id, identity from users order by identity');
```

...would get the first array at the top in the question.

Comment: why not change the original array construction?

Comment: Sure, but then I'd be doing the same thing in my query function, and if there's a native function that already does this (surely people have to do something like this a lot, working with databases), I'd rather use that.

Comment: no, your currently creating A and converting it to B why not create B in the first place?

Comment: +1 - this would be really useful generally when you are returning a set of rows from a DB

Comment: Is there any way to have the constructor list the identity first? If so, you could `array_unshift()` the value off the array and use it as a key for the modified array. If your question is there a built-in function to do this all at once, then the answer (as far as I know) is no.

Comment: I'm using PDO in my database, with query function wrappers to hide verbosity.  If there's a way to assign the identity with PDO, I'd do it, just not aware of it, but otherwise I'd have to give an argument to my query functions to say "turn into an associative array", and then put the above code into my query function.  Or I could just pass the query data to the function above.  But either way, that code would be in my codebase, and if there's a better way to do it, I'd like to do that.

Comment: @phpmycoder , I'm not farsighted enough to see whether that                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          would be a workable solution for different developers using different sql queries.  Would make it non-destructive, but still not sure whether the identity column can always be first in the sql.

Comment: I almost think that I've found an actual place where I'd like to use an anonymous function.  Too bad I'm stuck on php 5.2.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was thinking about shifting the first element off by applying array mapping the `array_unshift()` function then pairing the array returned by `array_map()` and the original array with `array_combine()`. Here's a sample, keep in mind it will only work when the identity element is the first element of the sub-arrays:

```
<?php
$arrs = array(
            array(
                'identity'=>'bob',
                'user_id'=>45,
                'name'=>'Bob'
            ),
            array(
                'identity'=>'tchalvak',
                'user_id'=>51, 
                'name'=>'TchalVak'
            )
        );

$identites = array_map( 'array_shift', $arrs );
$formatted = array_combine( $identites, $arrs );
print_r( $formatted );
?>
```

If necessary you could craft a helper function to pass to array map if the identity is not the first element.

```
<?php
$arrs = array(
            array(
                'identity'=>'bob',
                'user_id'=>45,
                'name'=>'Bob'
            ),
            array(
                'identity'=>'tchalvak',
                'user_id'=>51, 
                'name'=>'TchalVak'
            )
        );

$identites = array_map( 'array_grab', $arrs );
$formatted = array_combine( $identites, $arrs );
print_r( $formatted );

function array_grab( $array ) { return( $array['identity'] ); }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your array is to custom too have anything built in to PHP. You may be able to use [array_map](http://www.php.net/array_map) and save on a foreach, but that's not really saving much (and eliminating your `$identify_column` argument).

Comment: Right, array_map is the other possibility that I was considering jus' to avoid having a loop, but then I need a custom function or anonymous function support.

Essentially, I'm trying to say that the first array above is a standard database result array.  So it seems weird that associatively indexing it isn't something that people have done 100 times before.  

Perhaps the native php functions still don't account for that specific manipulation of multidimensional arrays, and just let specific developers solve it whenever it comes up, but I figured I'd try.

Comment: Well, assuming it is coming from a DB, why aren't you `$row = mysql_fetch_array($dbResult); $ary[$row['identity']] = $row;` in the first place? (or whatever your connection)

Comment: Excuse me, `$row = $dbc->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); $ary[$row['identity']] = $row;`

Comment: Well, then what I'd be doing is essentially the same thing as the `identity_associate` function that I created, I'd just be moving the argument to my query functions and the loop to inside my query functions. (For the cases when the loop is needed for multiple row results).  Different location, same type of loop.

Comment: I guess I'll just use that code if there isn't anything native that anyone knows of that fits better.

Comment: Correct, just the change made up-front instead of being applied as, arguably, a correction. short answer, I don't see a way of doing what you're looking for within PHP as-is. Admittedly I am not as versed with PHP as some people, but I don't think you're missing any secret function that does this for you. Maybe give it a couple of days and see what else turns up from other viewers. _(sorry I couldn't be of more help)_